# Conflict with glossaries package

Tags: errors

I was using the `glossaries` package without problem but now I'm receiving an error that I can't understand. I going to reduce my code as much as possible, sorry if it is not short enough.

Main File:

```
\documentclass[11 pt, letterpaper, oneside, openright]{book}
\listfiles 

\usepackage[spanish]{babel} % Manejo de idiomas
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[pages = some]{background} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}


%Acronym definitions

\newacronym{rcm}{RCM}{Reliability Centered Maintenance}
\newacronym{mcc}{MCC}{Mantenimiento Centrado en Confiabilidad}
\newacronym{amef}{AMEF}{Análisis de Modo y Efectos de Falla}
\newacronym{navair}{NAVAIR}{Naval Air Systems Command}
\newacronym{gmac}{GMAC}{Gestión de Mantenimiento Asistido por Computadora}
\newacronym{ircms}{IRCMS}{Integrated Reliability-Centered Maintenance System}
\newacronym{llc}{LLC}{Limited Liability Company}
% nomenclature:

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Lista de acrónimos]
\include{Chap4}
\end{document}
```

Chapter 4:

```
\chapter{Integración del \gls{mcc} con herramientas de Gestión de Mantenimiento Asistido por Computadora}
\label{Chap4}

\epigraph{La construcción exitosa de toda máquina depende de la perfección de las herramientas empleadas. Quien sea un maestro en el arte de la fabricación de herramientas poseerá la clave para la construcción de todas las máquinas}{Charles Babbage (1791- 1871)}


Existe un gran numero de compañías que se dedican a elaborar \gls{gmac}, en el presente trabajo se enumerara una pequeña fracción de este basto campo:

\begin{itemize}
\item Isograph Incorporation (Availability Workbench)
\item Aladon Network (Ivara EXP Professional)
\item JMS Software (RCM WorkSaver)
\end{itemize}
```

The following error arises:

```
LaTeX Info: Redefining \. on input line 35.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \% on input line 35.


! Package glossaries Error: Glossary entry `MCC' has not been defined.

See the glossaries package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.35 \include{Chap4}

You need to define a glossary entry before you can use it.


Overfull \hbox (316.00519pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
\OT1/cmr/m/sl/10.95 CAP[]ITULO 1.  INTEGRACI[]ON DEL  CON HERRAMIENTAS DE GESTI
[]ON DE MANTENIMIENTO ASISTIDO POR COMPUTADORA \OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 3
 []
```

It is an intermittent error but I don't know what is the reason for that. Thanks for your help

Comment: You haven't defined `gmac` (or `navair`). You also haven't defined `MCC` but I don't see where that is used in the code you posted.  Does the code you posted produce exactly that error?

Comment: Which of those packages are actually required to reproduce the problem? Is TikZ needed? Is `graphicx` (which is loaded by `tikz` anyway)? `background`? `epigraph`? `tabularx`? `tikz-qtree`? `biblatex`...? If you can reproduce the error without, delete them from the code you post here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the title of a chapter is capitalised. This doesn't affect commands (`\gls`) themselves, but it does affect their arguments (`mcc`). So, TeX looks for an acronym `MCC` which does not, of course, exist.

One possible work around - not necessarily the best, I'm not sure - is to use `\MakeLowercase{}`:

```
\chapter{Integración del \MakeLowercase{\gls{mcc}} con herramientas de Gestión de Mantenimiento Asistido por Computadora}
```

[image: chapter]

Complete code:

```
\begin{filecontents}{Chap4.tex}
  \chapter{Integración del \MakeLowercase{\gls{mcc}} con herramientas de Gestión de Mantenimiento Asistido por Computadora}
\label{Chap4}

\epigraph{La construcción exitosa de toda máquina depende de la perfección de las herramientas empleadas. Quien sea un maestro en el arte de la fabricación de herramientas poseerá la clave para la construcción de todas las máquinas}{Charles Babbage (1791- 1871)}


Existe un gran numero de compañías que se dedican a elaborar \gls{gmac}, en el presente trabajo se enumerara una pequeña fracción de este basto campo:

\begin{itemize}
\item Isograph Incorporation (Availability Workbench)
\item Aladon Network (Ivara EXP Professional)
\item JMS Software (RCM WorkSaver)
\end{itemize}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[11 pt, letterpaper, oneside, openright]{book}
\listfiles

\usepackage[spanish]{babel} % Manejo de idiomas
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[pages = some]{background}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}


%Acronym definitions

\newacronym{rcm}{RCM}{Reliability Centered Maintenance}
\newacronym{mcc}{MCC}{Mantenimiento Centrado en Confiabilidad}
\newacronym{amef}{AMEF}{Análisis de Modo y Efectos de Falla}
\newacronym{navair}{NAVAIR}{Naval Air Systems Command}
\newacronym{gmac}{GMAC}{Gestión de Mantenimiento Asistido por Computadora}
\newacronym{ircms}{IRCMS}{Integrated Reliability-Centered Maintenance System}
\newacronym{llc}{LLC}{Limited Liability Company}
% nomenclature:

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Lista de acrónimos]
\include{Chap4}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @jd1215 You're welcome. Once you revised the example, I could run the code and play around with it. I don't know if this is the best solution. Once I realised the problem, I just tried a couple of things until one worked. So it doesn't have a very solid theoretical foundation ;).